# Nodal Analysis using voltage sources

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws, nodal-analysis

Find v and i in the circuit of Fig.3.11
[image]

I modified the circuit like:
[image]

and renamed the nodal voltages:
[image]

Now applying KCL at the supernode,
$$i_1+i_2=3.5....(i)$$
We know, $$i_1=\frac{v_1}{\frac{12}{7}}, i_2=\frac{v_2}{\frac32} (\text{Note that }\frac{12}{7}=1.714)$$
From equation(i) we get
$$\begin{align}\\
\frac{7v_1}{12}+\frac{2v_2}{3} &=3.5\\
\implies 7v_1+8v_2 &=42.......(ii)\\
\end{align}\\
$$
To get the relationship between \$v_1\$ and \$v_2\$ we apply KVL to the following circuit
[image]

$$-v_2+v_1+6=0\\
\implies v_2=v_1+6.....(iii)$$
Now, from equation (ii),
$$7v_1+8(v_1+6)=42\\
\implies 15v_1=-6\\
\implies v_1=-0.4V$$
From equation (iii),
$$v_2= -0.4+6=5.6V$$
So, \$i_1=-\frac{7*0.4}{12}=-0.233A\$.
Hence, from the main figure \$v=-0.233*3=-0.699V\$.
But, in my book the answer is \$v=-400mV\$. Please tell where is my mistake.

Comment: First thing, your 3.5 A source is pointing the wrong way to be equivalent to the 14 V source it’s supposed to be replacing.

Comment: Converting the 14 V source to a current source makes the problem more difficult.

Comment: @Chu please add an answer. I couldn't find any other choice.

Comment: What are the three currents flowing away from the \$v\$ node?

Comment: @Chu I applied the KCL in the 3rd figure.  You can see there are three current around the supernode.

Comment: Yes, but there's no need to do the source transformation. From the original circuit diagram: \$\frac{v-14}{4}+\frac{v}{3}+\frac{v+6}{1.5}=0\$, hence \$v=-0.4\:V\$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu5Igy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_x+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_x=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_4
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

We also know that \$\text{V}_x=\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1\$.

Now, because you've to do the math to solve this. I will present a Mathematica code that will solve this problem:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == Ix + I2, Ix == I3 + I4, I1 == I2 + I5, I5 == I3 + I4, 
   I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (V2)/R3, I4 == (V2)/R4, 
   Vx == V2 - V1}, {Ix, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{Ix -> ((R3 + R4) (R1 Vx + R2 (Vi + Vx)))/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  I1 -> (R3 R4 Vi + R2 (R3 + R4) (Vi + Vx))/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  I2 -> (R3 R4 Vi - R1 (R3 + R4) Vx)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  I3 -> (R4 (R1 Vx + R2 (Vi + Vx)))/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  I4 -> (R3 (R1 Vx + R2 (Vi + Vx)))/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  I5 -> ((R3 + R4) (R1 Vx + R2 (Vi + Vx)))/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  V1 -> (R2 R3 R4 Vi - R1 R2 (R3 + R4) Vx)/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4), 
  V2 -> (R3 R4 (R1 Vx + R2 (Vi + Vx)))/(
   R1 R2 R3 + R2 R3 R4 + R1 (R2 + R3) R4)}}
```

Now, using your values we get:

```
In[2]:=R1 = 4;
R2 = 3;
R3 = 2;
R4 = 6;
Vi = 14;
Vx = 6;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == Ix + I2, Ix == I3 + I4, I1 == I2 + I5, I5 == I3 + I4, 
   I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (V2)/R3, I4 == (V2)/R4, 
   Vx == V2 - V1}, {Ix, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, V1, V2}]]

Out[2]={{Ix -> 56/15, I1 -> 18/5, I2 -> -(2/15), I3 -> 14/5, I4 -> 14/15, 
  I5 -> 56/15, V1 -> -(2/5), V2 -> 28/5}}
```

So, the answers are \$\text{v}=\text{V}_1=-\frac{2}{5}=-0.4\space\text{V}\$ and \$\text{i}=\text{I}_3=\frac{14}{5}=2.8\space\text{A}\$.

Comment: You did it absolutely correct!!

Comment: @AnkitaPal Thanks!